# JSON ajax keeps throwing undefined using Freebase API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jsonp

I want to read Freebase API http://smartsearch.kd.io . I managed to do one part but now I want to retrieve the geolocation coordinates and create a map but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my JS code :

```
    $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/paris?filter=/location/location/geolocation&key=AIzaSyAMWOvyMSupZsOHordVo1EawZbSkEySNVA&callback=?", function(data) {
                var card = $("<div>").attr({"class":"card"});
                var latlon=data.property["/location/location/geolocation"].values[0].text.split(" - ")[0] +","+data.property["/location/location/geolocation"].values[0].text.split(" - ")[1];
                var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
                var imgel = $("<img>").attr("src",img_url);
                imgel.appendTo(card);
                card.appendTo("body");
        });
```

Additional info you might need :
- Note that in smartsearch, I'm using $("#searchinput").val() instead of paris, but that doesn't change anything since it's not working even with paris.
- I think Google Maps isn't causing this.
- Cross origin requests isn't the problem since I managed to fetch other data from the website
- JSON file (removed callback parameter parsed by Jquery): https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/paris?filter=/location/location/geolocation&key=AIzaSyAMWOvyMSupZsOHordVo1EawZbSkEySNVA
- If you need the full JS code go to smartsearch.kd.io/js/script.js
- If the site is offline, that's probably koding limit (site shuts off 15 minutes after signing out of koding)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to do this kind of test multiple times:

```
if(data.property['/people/person/parents'].values.length) {
if(data.property['/people/person/children'].values.length) {
if(data.property['/people/person/sibling_s'].values.length) {
if(data.property["/location/location/geolocation"].values.length) {
```

and this is where your code is failing. You should make this test more reliable and stable, while also removing duplicated code.

Here's a helper function

```js
function dataHasProperty(data, property) {
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(property)) return false;
    if (!data[property].hasOwnProperty('values')) return false;
    return data[property].values.length;
}
```

And here's the improved tests:

```js
if(dataHasProperty(data, '/people/person/parents')) {
if(dataHasProperty(data, '/people/person/children')) {
if(dataHasProperty(data, '/people/person/sibling_s')) {
if(dataHasProperty(data, '/location/location/geolocation')) {
```

Comment: There is an error on line 222 of script.js where it hits `data.property['/people/person/date_of_birth'].values[0].text.split("T")[0]`. You will need to do this safer, by checking at every stage that the element actually exists. Write a helper function to sanitize the data. First have it check that `data.property['/people/person/date_of_birth']` exists. Then check that `data.property['/people/person/date_of_birth'].values[0]` exists. Then check that `data.property['/people/person/date_of_birth'].values[0].text` exists. etc. It is more work but will be more stable.

Comment: But you are right, it is the repeating test which is causing the problems

Comment: It doesn't throw any error for me, but I works if I remove the if-else condition.

Comment: Actually it's not the if condition (if(data.property["/location/location/geolocation"].values.length) {), If i put it on the top of the other check length conditions, the other ones are broken, but this one works

Comment: If you put it above line 222 it'll work. The error is at line 222 and execution stops there. That's why it works when you move the code higher.